# Mockito: can't verify a suspend function got called because of Continuation<T> function arguments NOT MATCHING under the hood

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing some unit tests for my defined `LocalDataSource` classes that wraps the functionality of a Room databse `DAO`, my code looks like this:

**Room DAO Interface**

```
@Dao
interface PersonDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(person: Person)

}
```

**LocalDataSource Class**

```
class PersonLocalDataSourceImpl(private val personDao: PersonDao) {

    suspend fun insert(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher, person: Person) =
        withContext(dispatcher) {
            personDao.insert(person)     // line 20
        }

}
```

**Unit Test Class**

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class PersonLocalDataSourceTest : BaseLocalDataSourceTest() {
    
    @Test
    fun givenPersonLocalDataSource_WhenInsertPerson_ThenPersonDaoInsertFunctionCalledOnce() =
        runBlockingTest {

            withContext(testCoroutineDispatcher) {

                val personDao = Mockito.mock(PersonDao::class.java)
                val personLocalDataSource = PersonLocalDataSourceImpl(personDao)
                val person = mockPerson()


                personLocalDataSource.insert(testCoroutineDispatcher, person)

                Mockito.verify(personDao).insert(person)   // line 36

            }
        }

}
```

I'm getting this error when running the test:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
personDao.insert( Person( id = ...) ),
Continuation at (my package).PersonLocalDataSourceTest$givenPersonLocalDataSource_WhenInsertPerson_ThenPersonDaoInsertFunctionCalledOnce$1$1.invokeSuspend(PersonLocalDataSourceTest.kt:37)

Actual invocation has different arguments:
personDao.insert(Person( id = ...),
Continuation at (my package).PersonLocalDataSourceImpl$insert$2.invokeSuspend(PersonLocalDataSourceImpl.kt:20)
```

**P.S.** the test passes when I change the definition of the function `PersonLocalDataSourceImpl::insert` like follows:

```
override suspend fun insert(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher, person: Person) =
            personDao.insert(person)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL:DR

You can use `coEvery` and `coVerify` to mock results and verify suspend functions. They become availbe when you declare `testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:"`.

In the following example I show how I do testing supsend functions.

### CoroutineRule

I'm using this custom Rule for testing.

```kotlin
class CoroutineRule(
  val testCoroutineDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher(),
    TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope(testCoroutineDispatcher) {

    override fun starting(description: Description?) {
        super.starting(description)
        Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description?) {
        super.finished(description)
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
        testCoroutineDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for calling [runBlockingTest] on a provided [TestCoroutineDispatcher].
     */
    fun runBlockingTest(block: suspend TestCoroutineScope.() -> Unit) {
        testCoroutineDispatcher.runBlockingTest(block)
    }
}
```

Let's define a simple `Repository` and a `Dao` interface.

```kotlin
class Repository(
  val dao: Dao,
  private val dispatcher: Dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) {

  suspend fun load(): String = withContext(dispatcher) { dao.load() }
}

interface Dao() {
  suspend fun load(): String 

  fun fetch(): Flow<String>
}
```

### Test Coroutines

To [mock coroutines](https://mockk.io/#coroutines) you need to add this dependency:

```
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:"
```

Then you can use `coEvery`, `coVerify`, `coMatch`, `coAssert`, `coRun`, `coAnswers` or `coInvoke` to mock suspend functions.

```kotlin
import io.mockk.coEvery
import io.mockk.coVerify
import io.mockk.mockk

class RepositoryTest {

  @get:Rule val coroutineRule = CoroutineRule()

  val dao: Dao = mockk()
 
  val classUnderTest: Respository = Repository(dao, coroutineRule.testCoroutineDispatcher)

  @Test
  fun aTest() = coroutinesRule.runBlockingTest {
    // use coEvery to mock suspend function results
    coEvery { dao.load() } returns "foo"

    // use normal every for mocking functions returning flow
    every { dao.fetch() } returns flowOf("foo")
    
    val actual = classUnderTest.load()

    // AssertJ
    Assertions.assertThat(actual).isEqual("foo")

    // use coVerify to verify calls to a suspend function
    coVerify { dao.load() }
  }
```

This way you do not need to do any context switch `withContext` in your test code. You just call `coroutineRule.runBlocking { ... }` and setup your expectations of your mocks. Then you can simply verify the result.

### Note

I think you should not pass the Dispatcher from outside. With Coroutines (and structured concurrency) the implementor (Library, Function, etc) knows best on which Dispatcher to run. When you have a function that reads from a DataBase, that function could use a certain Dispatcher like `Dispatchers.IO` (as you can see in my example).

With structured concurrency, the caller can dispatch the results on any other dispatcher. But it should not be responsible to decide which dispatchers down-stream function should use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with your last point **"implementor knows best on which Dispatcher to run"**, although, as I stated in my question, my problem is when using `Mockito::verify` function on an object suspend function which its implementation contains another suspend function call. Maybe Mockito doesn't work well with kotlin suspend functions.

Comment: I see. You can use `coEvery` and `coVerify` to mock and verify suspend functions. I updated the test in my answer. Hope that helps you.

Comment: In what package are those two functions defined?

Comment: They are available in `testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:"`. I updated my answer as well.

Comment: I think they are defined in here instead: https://mockk.io/ - I haven't seen those functions in the kotlinx-coroutines-core lib.

Comment: @César Muñoz You are right. They are in the mockk dependency. Thanks for mentioning.